# serializing a field in the model with many to one relation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a post model and an image model as follows:

```
class PropertyPost(models.Model):
    ....


class Image(models.Model):
    prop_post = models.ForeignKey(
        PropertyPost,
        related_name='images4thisproperty',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and here is their associated serializes:

```
class PropPostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
 images4thisproperty = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='image-detail')
      class Meta:
        model = PropertyPost
        fields = (...,images4thisproperty,...)



class ImageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    prop_post = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=PropertyPost.objects.all(),
                                             slug_field='pk')
      class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = (
            'url',
            'photo',
            'prop_post',
        )
```

now when I serialize my objects , the output json looks like this for propertypost model:

```
{
            "images4thisproperty": [
                "http://139.50.80.132/images/4",
                "http://139.50.80.132/images/3"
            ],
 }
```

and looks like this for Image model:

```
{
    "url": "http://139.50.80.132/images/1",
    "photo": "http://139.50.80.132/media/myposts/2019/20190327004444_8e3f5152-a3fd-40f2-857b-e16db3900fee.png",
    "prop_post": 1,
},
{
    "url": "http://139.50.80.132/images/2",
    "photo": "http://139.50.80.132/media/myposts/2019/20190327004450_659c207a-f3e1-471e-b2b0-c33c4708494a.png",
    "prop_post": 1,
},
```

I was wondering if I can have *photo* field of the Image model to be serialized in my propertypost too. in other words I would like to have this in my propertypost serializer output:

```
{
            "images4thisproperty": [
                "http://139.50.80.132/images/4",
                "http://139.50.80.132/images/3"
            ],
            "photo": [
                "http://139.50.80.132/media/myposts/2019/20190327004444_8e3f5152-a3fd-40f2-857b-e16db3900fee.png",
                "http://139.50.80.132/media/myposts/2019/20190327004450_659c207a-f3e1-471e-b2b0-c33c4708494a.png",
            ]

 }
```

Please let me know how can I do that,
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try modifing `PropSerializer`:

```
class PropPostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    images4thisproperty = ImageSerializer(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='image-detail')
    class Meta:
        model = PropertyPost
        fields = (...,images4thisproperty,...)
```